# How to check if a JFrame is open by checking it's one of the components are visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have this code sample in a separate `jDialog` (`jDialog` is in the same package as that of `JFrame`) which used to check (using a `Thread`) if the `jCheckBox1` in the `jFrame` is whether visible or not. `JDialog` is set to visible by clicking a `JLabel` (**Change Password**) in `JFrame`. I have not set the visibility of the `JFrame` even to `false` even after I click on the **Change Password** `JLabel`.

The problem I encountered is that even if the `JFrame` is **not visible** i.e when I run the `JDialog` separately (without clicking on the **Change Password** `JLabel`) it prints the **"Visible"** and I'm more than sure that the `jFrame` is not visible and not running.

This is the code snippet (`Thread`) I have used to check the visibility of the `JFrame`'s `jCheckBox1`:

```
LockOptions lock = new LockOptions();

private void setLocation2() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            boolean running = true;
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    if (lock.jCheckBox1.isVisible()) {
                        System.out.println("Visible");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not Visible");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

And this is the Code I have written in `JFrame`'s **Change Password** `JLabel`:

```
private void jLabel9MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    Container c = new ChangePassword(this, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

    if (!c.isShowing()) {
        c.setVisible(true);
        hideMeToSystemTray();
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

}
```

But when I run the `JDialog` separately (without clicking on the **Change Password** `JLabel`) it prints the **"Visible"**

I have attached a Screenshots of both `JFrame` and `JDialog`

`JFrame` containing `jCheckBox1`
[image: JFrame]

`JDialog`:

[image: JDialog]

Comment: [java.awt.Component.isVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible--): "Determines whether this component should be visible when its parent is visible. Components are initially visible, with the exception of top level components such as Frame objects.". So why not  checking the visibility of the frame iself? And what is `LockOptions` in your code?

Comment: @AxelRichter: LockOptions is the class name of the `JFrame`. Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Even if I check the visibility of the `JFrame` it says **Not Visible** even it is **Visible**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing--

Comment: Even if the `JFrame` is showing, the `Thread` in the `JDialog` is printing "Not Visible"

Comment: You say `LockOptions` "is the class name of the JFrame". At first: no it is not. Maybe `LockOptions` extends `JFrame`. But [In general Swing is not thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). So how do you think, your `Thread` gains access to your `lock` object?

Comment: Anything I can check my `JFrame` is opened?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's have the simplest possible example.

The following code creates a main frame having a button to create a new frame of class `LockOptionsWindow`, which extends `JFrame`.

The class `FrameDemo` implements `Runnable`. So can it be accessed on the event dispatching thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` as mentioned in [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). So it is possible creating a new thread `checklockoptionswindow` which then can check whether the new window created by the button is visible or not visible.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameDemo extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private LockOptionsWindow lockoptionswindow;
    private Thread checklockoptionswindow = new Thread();

    private void showLockOptionsWindow() {
        if (lockoptionswindow != null && lockoptionswindow.isDisplayable()) {
            lockoptionswindow.setVisible(true);
            lockoptionswindow.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
        } else {
            lockoptionswindow = new LockOptionsWindow();
            lockoptionswindow.setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
            lockoptionswindow.setVisible(true);
            lockoptionswindow.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
        }
    }

    private void startCheckLockOptionsWindow() {
        if (!checklockoptionswindow.isAlive()) {
            checklockoptionswindow = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    boolean running = true;
                    while (running) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            if (lockoptionswindow.isVisible()) {
                                if (lockoptionswindow.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
                                    System.out.println("Visible iconified");
                                } else  {
                                    System.out.print("Visible on screen ");
                                    int x = lockoptionswindow.getLocation().x;
                                    int y = lockoptionswindow.getLocation().y;
                                    System.out.println("at position " + x + ", " + y);
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Not Visible");
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            checklockoptionswindow.start();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        showLockOptionsWindow();
        startCheckLockOptionsWindow();
    }

    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Show LockOptions frame");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FrameDemo());
    }

    class LockOptionsWindow extends JFrame {
        public LockOptionsWindow() {
            super("LockOptions frame");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

Edited to determine whether the LockOptionsWindow is visible iconified only or is really showed as window on the screen.